# making a Hotel management system in BashScript

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

**I am unable to correct the error. I have tried searching on Google but i can't figure out what my output is referring to. Its giving a line number but the code is right there. "fi" is used at the end of IF statements in scriptfiles.
This is my code**

```
#!/bin/bash

#Declaring all fucntions

#Menu Display Function
set_menu_choice(){
clear
echo "---------------------------------------------"
echo "HOTEL RESERVATION"
echo "-------------------------------------------"
echo "1: BOOK A ROOM."
echo "2: TO VIEW YOUR DATA."
echo 'Please enter the choice: '
read menu_choice
}

#FOR HOTEL SELECTION
roombooking(){

#rtype=ROOM TYPE, hnum=HOTEL NUMBER, pr=PRICE RANGE, sty=DAYS OF STAY. 
$i, $j, $x, $rtype, $price, $sty, $bill; 
$r;
#
clear
echo "ENTER YOUR PRIZE RANGE MINIMUM(4000): "
read price
#
#Price Check
echo "HOTELS AVAILABLE"
if [[ $price -lt 4000 ]]; then
echo "SORRY NO HOTEL AVAILABLE IN THIS RANGE"
echo "ENTER YOUR PRIZE RANGE AGAIN MINIMUM(4000): "
read price
else if [[ ( $price -gt 4000 && $price -lt 5000 ) ]]; then  
echo "HOTEL RAMADA" 
#
elif [[ ( $price -gt 5000 && $price -lt 7000 ) ]]; then 
echo "1=>HOTEL RAMADA."
echo "2=>TAJ MAHAL."
#
elif [[ ( $price -gt 7000 && $price -lt 9000 ) ]]; then 
echo "1=>HOTEL RAMADA."
echo "2=>TAJ MAHAL."
echo "3=>HOTEL MEHRAN." 
#
elif [[ ( $price -gt 9000 && $price -lt 10000 ) ]]; then    
echo "1=>HOTEL RAMADA."
echo "2=>TAJ MAHAL."
echo "3=>HOTEL MEHRAN." 
echo "4=>MOVE AND PICK."    
#   
elif [[ $price -gt 10000 ]]
echo "1=>PEARL CONTINENTAL."
echo "2=>MOVE AND PICK."
echo "3=>HOTEL MEHRAN."
echo "4=>TAJ MAHAL."
echo "5=>HOTEL RAMADA."
fi
}

# Main Work
printf '\n\n\n'
printf 'Hotel Management System'

# Calling Options Display Function
set_menu_choice

if [[ $menu_choice == 1 ]]; then
roombooking
else
echo "Display Data"
fi

echo "finshed"
```

**I am attaching the output too**
[Error while running the bashscript file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEjJE.png)

EDIT: After adding `; then` in the last `elif` statement, I am getting the following error:

```
**Syntax Error Expected near Unexpected Token '}'**
```

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I'm not that familiar with bash, but are you just missing a `; then` on your last `elif` for prices > 10000?

Comment: Please, as stated in the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post: `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.`

Comment: Thanks @Cᴏʀʏ and everyone else. I saw the error too..soon after posting the question. thank you everyone for ur help

Comment: Sorry @hads0m . noted ur point . will refrain from using images from next time

Comment: Also, don't edit answers with new updates on your question please. Might get things confusing.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know that it will be updated on the answer provided. i thought i was editing the posted question.

Comment: Style point: do not ever write 6 consecutive echo lines.  Instead of doing echo multiple times, use `cat` with a heredoc (https://github.com/wrp/examples/blob/master/sh/heredoc).  It is much more readable.

Comment: what happens when someone enters exactly `4000`, `5000`, `7000`, `9000` or `10000`?

Comment: your first `else` test is written as `else if` which causes you to start a brand new `if/then/else` block, which in turn requires the 2nd `fi` at the end (see hads0m's answer); consider replacing `else if` with `elif` in order to eliminate the need for the 2nd `fi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're missing a `; then` here:

```
elif [[ $price -gt 10000 ]]
echo "1=>PEARL CONTINENTAL."
echo "2=>MOVE AND PICK."
echo "3=>HOTEL MEHRAN."
echo "4=>TAJ MAHAL."
echo "5=>HOTEL RAMADA."
fi
}
```

Second, you're getting a `syntax error near unexpected token '}'` because you did not close every statement. Just add a last `fi` after the current final one (inside the `roombooking` function also):

```
elif [[ $price -gt 10000 ]]; then
echo "1=>PEARL CONTINENTAL."
echo "2=>MOVE AND PICK."
echo "3=>HOTEL MEHRAN."
echo "4=>TAJ MAHAL."
echo "5=>HOTEL RAMADA."
fi
fi
}
```

Comment: also in your script it should be called as `elif` not as `else if [[ ( $price -gt 4000 && $price -lt 5000 ) ]]; then  echo "HOTEL RAMADA" `

Comment: @change198 i had missed that out. i had changed all else if's to elif but missed that one out. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: In that case you may have to remove the duplicate `fi` I pointed before, because it will not be needed anymore, as you just switched from an `if` to an `elif`. Just saying.